# How to get the effective Properties in Spring Boot application regardless of where it is defined?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-properties

suppose I define a property when starting my Spring Boot application from command line by passing `-Dmy.property=314` to JVM, and also I define this property in the `application.properties` :

```
my.property=318
```

to my knowledge the command line one has higher priority and when I inject the value of `my.property` in a bean I get `314`. is there any API that I can get properties regardless of where it is defined and respect this priority? I mean I get the property that will be injected in beans by Spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to inject the property via other mechanisms like `@Value` or bindings like `@ConfigurationProperties`, you can get it via `Environment`

```
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    ...
    env.getProperty("xxx.yyy");
```